# How do I display disabled suggestion item when using sap.m.Input

Tags: sapui5

I want to display a disabled suggestion item when user types something in input field.

The thing is that by default SAPUI5 hides all disabled suggestion items and I didn't find a way to convince the framework to reconsider its behavior.

Here is an example I created for your convenience: [example](https://jsbin.com/xucabowiba/1/edit?html,output)

Here is the code of the example:

```
<Input showSuggestion="true" filterSuggests="false" autocomplete="false">
      <suggestionItems>
        <core:Item text="item 1" key="1" enabled="true"/>
        <core:Item text="item 2" key="2" enabled="false"/>
        <core:Item text="item 3" key="3" enabled="true"/>
        <core:Item text="item 4" key="4" enabled="true"/>
      </suggestionItems>
</Input>
```

If you type "item" in the input field, you won't see item 2 in suggestions.

Is there a way to display item 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with a combination of custom data aggregation and CSS.

XML:

```
<core:Item text="item 2" key="2" >
   <core:customData>
      <core:CustomData key="disable-suggestion-item" value="true" writeToDom="true"/>
   </core:customData>
</core:Item>
```

CSS:

```
[data-disable-suggestion-item="true"]{
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

here is working [solution](https://jsbin.com/kozacavaju/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for, but hey, it works:)

Comment: There is no direct way to achieve this so work-around is the way to go :)